# In Bondi gauge/coordinate, how to obtain covariant derivative of the 2-dimemsional sphere using null projection operators?

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems

In Bondi coordinate , [the Bondi-Sachs metric](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bondi-Sachs_Formalism#The_Bondi-Sachs_metric) is written as
$$
ds^2=-\frac{V}{r}e^{2\beta}du^2-2e^{2\beta}dudr+r^2h_{AB}(dx^A-U^Adu)(dx^B-U^Bdu)
$$
Before any decomposition, the covariant derivative $D_A$ of the metric $h_{AB}$ has been used in Einstein equation, frequently. For example in [Scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bondi-Sachs_Formalism#Einstein_equations_and_their_Bondi-Sachs_solution).

My naive consideration comes from 3+1 formalism. The spatial covariant derivative can be derived from
$$
D\equiv\gamma^* \nabla
$$
where $\gamma^*$ is projective operator and $\nabla$ is covariant derivative of space-time.

I wonder how to obtain covariant derivative of the 2-dimemsional sphere using null projection operators? Or is there null foliation referred to Bondi gauge?